# Android - 3 same everyday notifications. How to launch?

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarm

I have a huge problem with creating notifications.

Situation:
[image]

I have a MainActivity. And it is, obviosly, first activity. And I have a SettingsActivity, wich contains few CheckBoxes. These CheckBoxes can turn on/off notifications. At maximum, there can be 3 active notifications.

Now about notifications in more details. They are just notifications with image, title and small content.

I have a code to create them:

```
int notificationId = 001;

    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent viewPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
                    .setContentText("Notification Content")
                    .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);



    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

This code works fine. But the main problem is that I have to create those notifications every day at different time (for example: 10:00 for 1 notification, 13:00 for 2 and 18:00 for 3). I know, that I have to use AlarmManager here, but where and how should I setup these notifications? In MainActivity? In SettingsActivity?

And one more problem. These notifications have to be created even after device restart.

My app is almost ready and the last stage of developing is this "notifications" problem.

Help me to solve this problems please.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/    here is tutorial which you can follow to solve your problem, you have to set this notification in on reciieve method of broadcast reciever. if you feel difficulty after this tutorial then i will explain more in detail

Comment: Unfortunately, I have some problems with your tutorial too :(